# How to toggle particular tag or component on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have an UI which I am rendering with dynamic data, Inside which I have an editable button on click of which I am hiding one field and rendering one new field that is select option.

**Issue**

As I am rendering my data dynamically so edit field is in each div so when I am clicking edit it is changing all divs,  I want to change the particular div only

**Code**

```
const Evaluation = props => {
  const [visible, setvisible] = useState(true);

  let empData = [
    {
      firstName: "name1",
      lastName: "lastname1",
      class: "5"
    },
    {
      firstName: "name2",
      lastName: "last name2",
      class: "6"
    }
  ];

  const onClickEdit = () => {
    setvisible(false);
  };
  const cancelOnClick = () => {
    setvisible(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      {empData.map(item => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="form-group col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  disabled
                  id="firstName"
                  value={item.firstName}
                />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="firstName" className="labelEmploye">
                  First name
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  disabled
                  id="lastname"
                  value={item.lastName}
                />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="lastname" className="labelEmploye">
                  Last Name
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            {visible ? (
              <div className="row">
                <div className="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    disabled
                    id="Evaluation"
                    value={item.class}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <label htmlFor="Evaluation" className="labelEmploye">
                    Evaluation
                  </label>

                  <div className="form-group mt-2">
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary form-control col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"
                      onClick={onClickEdit}
                    >
                      Edit
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="row">
                <div className="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                  <select className="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                  </select>

                  <button
                    onClick={cancelOnClick}
                    className="btn btn-warning form-control col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 m-2"
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                  <button className="btn btn-success form-control col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 m-2">
                    Save
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-rhodes-go3lm?file=/src/App.js:0-3624)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easier way to do that. See the working demo here: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-waterfall-likvr?file=/src/App.js)

Basically, set the `empData` in your state directly, and add an `edit` field to each of the objects.

```
const [empData, setEmpData] = useState([
    {
      firstName: "name1",
      lastName: "lastname1",
      class: "5",
      edit: false
    },
    {
      firstName: "name2",
      lastName: "last name2",
      class: "6",
      edit: false
    }
]);
```

Add the index as well in the items where you map it:

```
empData.map((item, index) => ())
```

Now you can use the `edit` field to hide/show the edit options:

```
{!item.edit ? () : ()}
```

On the buttons you pass values like this:

```
 onClick={() => onClickEdit(index)}
 onClick={() => cancelOnClick(index)}
```

And your functions would be:

```
const onClickEdit = index => {
    let data = [...empData];
    data[index].edit = true;
    setEmpData(data);
};

  const cancelOnClick = index => {
    let data = [...empData];
    data[index].edit = false;
    setEmpData(data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because

---

```
      const [visible, setvisible] = useState(true);
```

---

is shared state for all what gonna be in App.js, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to shift this and other relevant code from App.js to different component

---

```
    empData.map(item => <ItemComponent item={item} />)
```

---

and in it copy all UI code + the state above. now each component will create his own `visible` flag

---

```
  function ItemComponent({item}) {
    const [visible, setvisible] = useState(true);
    return( 
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="form-group col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
            <input
              type="text"
              disabled
              id="firstName"
              value={item.firstName}
            />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="firstName" className="labelEmploye">
              First name
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <input
              type="text"
              disabled
              id="lastname"
              value={item.lastName}
            />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="lastname" className="labelEmploye">
              Last Name
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        {visible ? (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
              <input
                type="text"
                disabled
                id="Evaluation"
                value={item.class}
              />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="Evaluation" className="labelEmploye">
                Evaluation
              </label>

              <div className="form-group mt-2">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary form-control col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"
                  onClick={onClickEdit}
                >
                  Edit
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <select className="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
              </select>

              <button
                onClick={cancelOnClick}
                className="btn btn-warning form-control col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 m-2"
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-success form-control col-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 m-2">
                Save
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
   )
  }
```